# How can I pass a parameter or value from one view to another through a redirect to action?

Tags: model-view-controller, redirecttoaction

I have a 'login' view and a 'reset password' view in my MVC project.

After a successful reset password action, I redirect back to the 'login' view.

I'd like the 'login' view to have a means of checking whether a successful password reset has just happened so it can display a confirmation/success message to the user. What's the best mechanism for this?

I tried adding to the view bag and the view data from the reset view and have the login view see if there's a value related to resetting in the bag or data, but the bag is reset after the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TempData also works; albeit not the prettiest solution. 
It may be worthwhile to investigate the solution referenced by rism which I plan to do.

```
TempData.Add("ForgotPassword", true);
TempData.Add("UserEmail", model.Email);
```

Comment: setting this as the answer for now since it does work; although not the most graceful or solutions....

Answer (score 2):

I use this style from [Jon Krugers Blog](http://jonkruger.com/blog/2009/04/06/aspnet-mvc-pass-parameters-when-redirecting-from-one-action-to-another/):

```
[PassParametersDuringRedirect]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AcceptGet]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexPresentationModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptPost]
    public ActionResult Save(SaveUpdateModel model)
    {
        // save the information

        var presentationModel = new IndexPresentationModel();

        presentationModel.Message = model.Message;

        return this.RedirectToAction(c => c.Index(presentationModel));
    }
}
```

And then the helper method to make that happen:

```
protected RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<T>(Expression<Action<T>> action)
    where T : Controller
{
    return ControllerExtensions.RedirectToAction(this, action);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store it in the session variable

On your password reset controller

```
if (login == "success")
{
     Session["loginStatus"] = "success";
}else{
     Session["loginStatus"] = "failed";
}
```

On your Login Controller

```
public actionresult Login()
{
    if (Session["loginStatus"] == "success")
    {
         return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "Controller");
    }

}
```

Although Session variables are not always the best way to store info..you could always create a class that has a property that will you can access across the site.

ViewData and ViewBag seem to get cleared across controller calls but Session should live through the entire Session. Hope this works.